# It's a question from me as I am a beginner in programming ? I want to ask a simple question related to Python

Tags: python

The question is, i executed a program which told me to input a name. Now whenever I input a number as the input instead of letters or a string. The number gets taken as my name. I want the program to tell me to enter a name and not a number whenever I type in a number as my name instead of a string. Can you please help me with this problem in Python. I want a simple code and should not contain any import functions as I don't know about it ! Only simple begineers code please.
Here's my code:

```
name = input("Enter a name : ")
print("Hello", name)
```

Whenever I enter a number as input for example 5, then it prints Hello 5 but I want it to print Please Enter A Valid Name whenever I input a number. Please Help !

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One very simple solution is to use the built-in function [`isnumeric()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric), which returns true if all characters in the string are numeric.

```
name = input("Enter a name : ")
if name.isnumeric():
    print("That's not a name!")
else:
    print("Hello", name)
```

Another approach is to use [`isalpha()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha), which returns true if all characters in the string are letters.

```
name = input("Enter a name : ")
if name.isalpha():
    print("Hello", name)
else:
    print("That's not a name!)
```

Be careful though, as this will reject some strings that are still names, such as "John Smith" or "Jean-Pierre"

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a string, you can use regular expressions to find out if it contains undesirable characters, as per the following transcript:

```
>>> import re

>>> name = input("Name? ")
Name? Pax
>>> if re.search("[0-9]", name):
...     print("Has digits")
...

>>> name = input("Name? ")
Name? Bobby27
>>> if re.search("[0-9]", name):
...     print("Has digits")
...
Has digits
```

This particular case checks whether *any* digits exist in the string but you can make the regular expression arbitrarily complex if you want more targeted checks to be done.